# Using yield, print and return in python function

Tags: python

Can someone help me identify what im doing wrong below:

```
def SeeIfExactRangeIsFound():
    with open(logfile) as input_data:
        mylist = []
        for line in input_data:
            if BeginSearchDVar in line:  # Or whatever test is needed
                print line.strip()
                #mylist.append((line.strip()))
                #return mylist
                break
        for line in input_data:  # This keeps reading the file
            if line.strip() == EndinSearchD:
                break
            print line
            #mylist.append((line))
            #return mylist
#SeeIfExactRangeIsFound()
LRange = SeeIfExactRangeIsFound()
print LRange
```

I'm looping through a file and only printing out sections of that file. As in, I start printing content of logfile when a specific pattern is found in the line being read. and continue printing all lines after that first line until a line containing the pattern found in EndingSearchD variable is found.

this works with the "print".  but as you can see, I want to store the output of the SeeIfExactRangeIsFound function in a variable and use the content of that variable later on.

My problem is, despite my attempts (commented out below) to try different ways to accomplish my goal, none of it seems to work.  I feel I'm so close to the answer but I spent 2 hours on this and can't figure it out.

any ideas?

Comment: `return` will immediately break you out of the function and the rest of the code will not be executed, so it has no place in the first `for` loop. The second loop can't work at all because you've exhausted the file (you can only iterate through a file object once unless you reset back to the first line, or transfer the contents of the file to some other container e.g. a list and iterate that). That said, I'm not sure I can give a definitive answer to give the output you expect because it's not clear to me.

Comment: Uncomment both `append`s. Replace the second `break` with `return mylist`.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, it only prints. So, first think about whether that is right and whether it should return or yield anything and what that should be. Please also upgrade to Python 3 right away, starting to learn the old Python 2 will partially be a waste of time.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt it did return something though. I think the OP is asking why the parts that are commented out aren't working (and not because they're commented out :) )

Comment: That's true, @roganjosh, it returns `None`. However, that's not helpful, especially if you take into account the "yield" in the topic. What I have in mind is that the function defines an interface and that needs to be defined. However, the intended interface isn't clear yet, but you are discussing the implementation already.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm not sure what you're saying there. I also wasn't referring to it returning `None` (which it will in its current form). I'm saying that there are `return` statements in the code that the OP has just chosen to comment out because they did not work as the OP intended. I don't know why they commented them out because the code still doesn't work without them. But I think the content of the commented-out lines are the focus of the OP's question.

Comment: i want what is printed out to be stored in LRange variable.  In other words, when you run the function, it prints out the range of lines it is expected to print out. But instead of it printing out to stdout, i want the range of lines stored in a variable. Hopefully, i have clarified things sufficiently.  Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Have you tried using `yield`? You mention it in the title. What do think will happen if you do `yield line` instead of `print line`? Why not try it and see if you're right? If it's what you want, great; if it's close and you can't figure out how to get it exactly right, you can ask for help with that; if it's not right at all, and you can't figure out why, you can ask about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it, but your return statement is not in the proper scope:

```
def SeeIfExactRangeIsFound():
    with open(logfile) as input_data:
        mylist = []
        for line in input_data:
            if BeginSearchDVar in line:  # Or whatever test is needed
                print line.strip()
                mylist.append((line.strip()))
                break
        for line in input_data:  # This keeps reading the file
            if line.strip() == EndinSearchD:
                break
            print line
            mylist.append((line))
       return mylist
```

as bonus, you can easily transform this into a generator:

```
def SeeIfExactRangeIsFound():
    with open(logfile) as input_data:
        for line in input_data:
            if BeginSearchDVar in line:  # Or whatever test is needed
                yield line.strip()
        for line in input_data:  # This keeps reading the file
            if line.strip() == EndinSearchD:
                break
            yield line
```

and consume it like:

```
results = [x for x in def SeeIfExactRangeIsFound()]
```

Answer (score 1):

a version matching your description instead of your code

> I start printing content of logfile when a specific pattern is found
>   in the line being read. and continue printing all lines after that
>   first line until a line containing the pattern found in EndingSearchD
>   variable is found.

```
def SeeIfExactRangeIsFound():
    with open(logfile) as input_file:
        input_data = input_file.readlines()
    mylist = []
    allow_yielding = False
    for line in input_data:
        if BeginSearchDVar in line:
            allow_yielding = True
        if allow_yielding:
            yield line
        if line.strip() == EndinSearchD:
            break
LRange = SeeIfExactRangeIsFound()
print LRange
```